# MariaDB (MySQL?) Unable to create foreign key - REFERENCES command denied

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I'm on MariaDB trying to set a foreign key on a table called isotemp referencing another table, called ISO-3166-2-status. I had added references to all previous tables in the same database with the same user before, but this time `Error Code: 1142. REFERENCES command denied to user 'symfony'@'localhost' for table 'ISO-3166-2-status.id'` happened. I went to consult the docs at (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/grant/#table-privileges) and noticed the REFERENCES privilege is documented as "Unused" in both table as column contexts.

When I connected as root the command `GRANT REFERENCES ON geo.* TO symfony@localhost;` executes without error, although the error message persists. I then tried executing `GRANT REFERENCES ON geo.ISO-3166-2-status to symfony@localhost;` and `GRANT REFERENCES ON geo.isotemp to symfony@localhost;` which both executed without error, and the following is the output from the `SHOW GRANTS` command, as user `symfony`:

```
GRANT FILE, REFERENCES ON *.* TO 'symfony'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '************'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `geo`.* TO 'symfony'@'localhost'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `symfony`.* TO 'symfony'@'localhost'
GRANT REFERENCES ON `geo`.`ISO-3166-2-status` TO 'symfony'@'localhost'
GRANT REFERENCES ON `geo`.`isotemp` TO 'symfony'@'localhost'
```

...but still I cannot create the foreign key. The foreign key command in question:

```
alter table isotemp add foreign key(statusid) references `ISO-3166-2-status`.`id`;
```

Here are my tables:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `isotemp`;

CREATE TABLE `isotemp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alpha` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `statusid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=657 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

SHOW CREATE TABLE `ISO-3166-2-status`;

CREATE TABLE `ISO-3166-2-status` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` char(24) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I have tried reconnecting and restarting the server, to no avail. Please tell me I'm overlooking something obvious. Eternal gratitude.

Comment: You can try: `ALTER TABLE isotemp
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (fk_statusid) REFERENCES ISO-3166-2-status (id);`

Comment: That didn't work, although `ALTER TABLE isotemp ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (statusid) REFERENCES ISO-3166-2-status(id);` was successful. Thanks for the pointer. I was certain I tried that already, but I guess I was mistaken. Any idea as to why this form should take effect, while the other one doesn't?

Comment: Because according to MariaDB documentation this is the way to add a foreign key to an already created table.

Answer (score 1):

The way it should be done is as follows.

```
ALTER TABLE isotemp ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (statusid) REFERENCES ISO-3166-2-status(id);
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

What user Hackerman suggested; with MariaDB you, apparently, have to use

```
ALTER TABLE <table1> ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(fk) REFERENCES <table2>(uk);
```

to add a foreign key to an already created table. Thanks a million, Hackerman!